# select child checkboxes doesn't work with jquery 1.72

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox, version

I'm trying to create a checkbox that controls the children checkboxes of a UL list... this works in jquery 1.4 but not in 1.72.  What am I doing wrong here?  I think its the selector but can't figure it out.

```
  $(".checkboxFilter input:checkbox").change(function () {
        $(".checkboxFilter").find(':checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/johncmolyneux/pqLts/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:checkbox` selector are deprecated, try using the `$('[type=checkbox]')` method

Comment: I think you meant, :checkbox selector is deprecated, use the  $('[type=checkbox]') instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $(":checkbox").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
    });
});​
```

//OR

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", this.checked);
    });
});​
```

**[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/pqLts/7/)**